# Express.js - get selected item rows from a table in ejs

Tags: node.js, express, view, ejs, body-parser

I'm trying to get selected rows from a table in express js.

Here is a html+ejs table code I have in my ejs view file. I'm trying to get only the rows where the checkbox is checked.

```
                  <table class="table">
                    <thread class = "thread-inverse">
                      <tr>
                        <th>Item Id</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Category</th>
                        <th>Manufacturer</th>
                        <th>Supplier</th>
                        <th>Buying Price</th>
                        <th>Selling Price</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                      </tr>
                      <% for(var i =0; i < itemList.length; i++){%>
                        <tr>
                          <td><%= itemList[i].productId %></td>
                          <td><%= itemList[i].itemName %></td>
                          <td><%= itemList[i].category %></td>
                          <td><%= itemList[i].manufacturer %></td>
                          <td><%= itemList[i].supplier %></td>
                          <td><%= itemList[i].buyingPrice %></td>
                          <td><%= itemList[i].sellingPrice %></td>
                          <td><input type="text" name="quantity""></td>
                          <td><input type="checkbox" name="productId" value="<%= itemList[i].productId %>"> | ADD </td>
                        </tr>

                      <% } %>
                    </thread>
                  </table>
```

I have tried several things but nothing is working.. 
Can anyone please give me a solution ?

Comment: What are you trying to do?
EJS is templating engine, which creates HTML file from a template when a user requests some route. It is not what you use to interact with express in runtime. You will need to use javascript and a ajax call to pass the checked value to Express.

Comment: It's a MVC application.  ejs is the view file here. I simply need to view a item-list and to user and get selected rows in post requset.  I'm passing the "itemList" from controller and generating the table inside a form. Now I need to select particular item rows. Please let me know If there a better way to do this ?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to get results form a database query. Even if you aren't, we need to see your server-side code where you are rendering this EJS template.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code a bit,

```
//HTML
//add a **onclick** listener on checkbox

<td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="productId" value="<%= itemList[i].productId %>"> | ADD </td>


//In java script file

$('.checkbox').click(function() {
  var productId  = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(0)').text();
  //changing td:eq(x) will give you corresponding clicked row's cell

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the following way, and works well.

Modify the code snippet by adding class name to :

```
    <% for(var i =0; i < itemList.length; i++){%>
        <tr class="tbl-item">
...
    <% } %>
```

And implement the click function:

```
$(".checkbox").each(function(index) {
        $(this).click(function(e) {
            let item = $(".tbl-item")[index];
            console.log(item);
        }) ;
    })
```

Then the console will show the desired tag data and you can get every item like:
item.children[4].innerText

Thanks.